# How to assert value in json file using groovy?

Tags: groovy

i want to assert values between 2 json files.
Here is the code i tried, it works fine but i have more than 300 values to test.
Instead of having 300 lines is there a better way to do it with a loop :

file1.json content is:

```
[
 {
   "Name": "Pierre",
   "Address": 1,
   "City": "Paris",
   "Country": "FRA",
   "Code": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
   "Position": " 7000,00  $ "
 },
 {
   "Name": "Pierre",
   "Address": 2,
   "City": "Paris",
   "Country": "USA",
   "Code": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
   "Position": " 9000,00  $ "
 },
 {
   "Name": "Pierre",
   "Address": 3,
   "City": "Paris",
   "Country": "GER",
   "Code": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
   "Position": " 2000,00  $ "
 }
 ]
```

file2.json content is:

```
{"value": {
    "data": {"number1": [ 
[
 {
   "Name": "Pierre",
   "Address": 1,
   "City": "Paris",
   "Country": "FRA",
   "Code": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
   "Position": " 7000,00  $ "
 },
 {
   "Name": "Paul",
   "Address": 2,
   "City": "Paris",
   "Country": "USA",
   "Code": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
   "Position": " 9000,00  $ "
 },
 {
   "Name": "Pierre",
   "Address": 3,
   "City": "Paris",
   "Country": "GER",
   "Code": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
   "Position": " 2000,00  $ "
 },
   "Name": "Luc",
   "Address": 6,
   "City": "Pekin",
   "Country": "CHN",
   "Code": "2020-01-01T00:00:00",
   "Position": " 800,00  $ "
 },
 ]
 ]
 }
```

i want to assert each value of file1 with file2.
For exemple:

```
JsonSlurper jsonSlurper1 = new JsonSlurper()
File file1Actual = new File('c:/temp/file1.json')
def actualJson = jsonSlurper1.parse(file1Actual)

JsonSlurper jsonSlurper2 = new JsonSlurper()
File file2Expected = new File('c:/temp/file2.json')
def expectedJson = jsonSlurper2.parse(file2Expected)

assert actualJson.value.data.number1.Name[0] == expectedJson.Name[0]
assert actualJson.value.data.number1.Name[1] == expectedJson.Name[1]
assert actualJson.value.data.number1.Name[2] == expectedJson.Name[2]
```

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: hi file1 has extra {"value": {
    "data": {"number1": [ is that intended ?

Comment: Your code example is in Groovy, not Java. You may want to edit the tags.

Comment: If you don't mind the complex error message (for >300 items that is): `actualJson.value.data.number1*.Name == expectedJson*.Name`

Comment: I'm using [JSONAssert](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert) for this in my unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are actually coding in Groovy (not Java) as your code example suggests, something like the following should do it:

```
/* ... read in the Json files as outlined in the question ... */
actualJson.value.data.number1.size.times {
    // Just to demonstrate that 'it' takes on values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.
    println "assert number ${it}"
    assert actualJson.value.data.number1.Name[it] == expectedJson.Name[it]
}
```

However this is a very 'groovyesque' way of doing it. If you want something a tad closer what a Java developer would write, you would maybe do:

```
/* read in Jsons, then: */
// Let's assign the list to a var for better readability
def actualList = actualJson.value.data.number1

// Bonus points for asserting that both lists are of equal size
// assert actualList.size == expectedJson.size
// If this does not hold then
def smaller = Math.min(actualList.size, expectedJson.size)

// a classic for-loop.
for (int i = 0; i < smaller; i++) {
    println "assert number ${i}"
    assert actualList[i].Name == expectedJson[i].Name
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for my mistake, yes it`s groovy. @afrischke thank your help, i try now...

Comment: Hi, i redited my question. this line assert actualList[i].Name == expectedJson[i].Name cannot be true because the second file has more values with Name

Comment: Okay, so if this assumption does not hold, you will need to modify the loop condition accordingly.

Comment: Modified the second example to work with lists of unequal length.